# Фильтрация значений инпутов

Tags: php

Видел, как таким способом фильтруют значения инпутов. Решил попробывать.

Но почему у меня значения инпутов не записываются в переменные?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="contact_form">
            <label for="name">Введите имя:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="contact_form">
            <label for="age">Введите возраст:</label>
            <input type="text" name="age"/>
        </div>
        <div class="contact_form">
            <label for="salary">Введите зарплату:</label>
            <input type="text" name="salary"/>
        </div>  

        <div class="btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Нажать" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST METHOD') === 'POST'){
    $username = filter_iput(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $age = filter_iput(INPUT_POST, 'age');
    $salary = filter_iput(INPUT_POST, 'salary');
}

if(!$username){
    $errors[] = 'Name can not be empty';
}
if(!$age){
    $errors[] = 'Age can not be empty';
}
if(!$salary){
    $errors[] = 'Salary can not be empty';
}

if(!$errors){
    echo "Good";
}
var_dump($errors);

?>
```

Вывод:

> var_dump:if(!$errors){array(3) { [0]=> string(21) "Name can not be empty" [1]=> string(20) "Age can not be empty" [2]=> string(23) "Salary can not be empty" }

Comment: А где подчеркивание в `"REQUEST METHOD"`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev спасибо)) пора заканчивать наверное сидеть)) уже ничего не вижу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не ошиблись с filter_iput? Кажется, должно быть filter_input